# Holonomy group of a dense, open submanifold

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, holonomy

I have a Riemannian manifold $(X,g)$, where $X$ is not necessarily compact or complete, and a dense open submanifold $Y \subseteq X$. In my case $X$ is a smooth quasi-projective variety over the complex numbers and $Y$ is an open subvariety, so that $X \setminus Y$ is not a very complicated set.

I need to understand how the (restricted) holonomy groups of $X$ and $Y$ compare. I suspect they should be equal, but I could not find any place in the literature that discusses this. Any help or reference is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If the metric $g$ is real analytic then both (restricted) holonomies are equal. For a proof see Theorem 10.8, page 101 in Chapter II, paragraph 10 of Kobayashi-Nomizu, vol I, (1963).

Comment: That solves the problem that I had in mind. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: You are welcome. I am happy your metric is real analytic !